# randomized SVD singular values

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, random-matrices

randomized SVD decomposes a matrix by extracting the first k singular values/vectors using k+p random projections.

my question concerns the singular values that are output from the algorithm. why aren't the values equal to the first k-singular values if you do the full SVD?

Below I have a simple implementation in R.

```
    rsvd = function(A, k=10, p=5) {
       n = nrow(A)
       y = A %*% matrix(rnorm(n * (k+p)), nrow=n)
       q = qr.Q(qr(y))
       b = t(q) %*% A
       svd = svd(b)
       list(u=q %*% svd$u, d=svd$d, v=svd$v)
       }

> set.seed(10)

> A <- matrix(rnorm(500*500),500,500)

> svd(A)$d[1:15]
 [1] 44.94307 44.48235 43.78984 43.44626 43.27146 43.15066 42.79720 42.54440 42.27439 42.21873 41.79763 41.51349 41.48338 41.35024 41.18068

> rsvd.o(A,10,5)$d
 [1] 34.83741 33.83411 33.09522 32.65761 32.34326 31.80868 31.38253 30.96395 30.79063 30.34387 30.04538 29.56061 29.24128 29.12612 27.61804
```

Comment: Do you have any reference for this algorithm?

Comment: "Randomized algorithms for the low-rank approximation of matrices"

http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/randsurvey.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be approximation to the true singular values (with suitable hypotheses, with good probability...).
Intuitively, it is like trying to infer the singular values of a $n\times n$ matrix by looking at its leading $(k+p)\times (k+p)$ submatrix only and replacing the rest with zeros: it is cheaper to compute, but yields only an approximate result.

Where does the "randomized" part come into play? Well, depending on the specific matrix, the $(k+p)\times (k+p)$ submatrix may not be representative of the whole matrix: so, we conjugate everything with a random orthogonal matrix $Q$ that mixes up everything and ensures that there is "nothing special" regarding the first $k+p$ entries with respect to the rest.